# If $y'(x) =y(x)-x +1$ and $y(0)=1$ then $y^{(n)}(0) = 1$ for every $n\ge2$

Tags: taylor-expansion

Start of the taylor series:

```
f(x) = f(0)
```

Which from the question is 1.

```
f(x) = 1 

f'(0) = y - 0 + 1
```

The current y value is 1 so the rate of change is therefore:

```
f'(0) = 1 + 1 = 2
```

Now add the next term

```
f''(x) = d(y-x+1)/dx = y'(x)  - 1

f''(0)=  y'(x)  - 1 
f''(0)=  2 - 1 = 1

f'''(x) = d(y'(x) - 1)/dx = y''(x)  =1
```

And then I guess it just goes on like this :

```
f''''(x) = d(y'''(x)=y''(x)=1)/dx =  = 1
```

I don't have t he solutions manual but I think the above is correct ?

Comment: I am confused by f(x), y(x) and y. Why do you write $f^{''}(x)=y'(x)-1$ and in the next line $f^{''}(0)=y'(x)-1$?

Comment: stupidiy b.c with implicit differentiation I always wrote y'(x)

Comment: Why using Taylor series ? It is aesy to find the solution of the ODE :  $y=x+Ce^x$. And with the condition $y(0)=1$ : $$y(x)=x+e^x$$ All successive derivatives except the first are equal to $e^x$ and so, are equal to 1 at $x=0$.

Comment: b.c the book says

Comment: Would you trust the book, or your own eyes?